# How to get the exception error as Object in Nestjs Validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, class-validator

By default, when validation fails the response came out like

```
{
    statusCode: 400,
    message: [ 'Provide a url.', 'test must be a string' ],
    error: 'Bad Request'
}
```

How can I get the value of messages as:

```
{
    statusCode: 400,
    message: {
        "url": 'Provide a url.',
        "test": 'test must be a string'
    },
    error: 'Bad Request'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `ValidationPipe` you can pass an `exceptionFacotry` property to the options and format your errors as you want. Something like this would probably get you on the right path

```js
exceptionFactory: (errors) => {
  const errorMessages = {};
  errors.forEach(error => {
    errorMessages[error.property]= Object.values(error.contraints).join('. ').trim();
  });
  return new BadRequestException(errorMessages);
}
```

Comment: I think it should '=' not ':'

Comment: `exceptonFactory` is a property of the`options` __object__ passed to the `ValidationPipe`, so `:` is correct here

Comment: in typescript it's '=' instead of ':'

Comment: You're right, was thinking it was a raw object, not an assignment.

Comment: It will not return nested error message.